# Ruby on Rails 3: setting fixed locale on specific route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I've installed [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) gem on my localized site (3 languages) and i need administration zone (/admin) to be always in English. Any idea how to do that? Maybe I can force locale for route?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't used rails_admin but a quick scan of it's repo would indicate it's using whatever locale is set in you app. I'm guessing you set that in a before_filter in your application.rb via one of the methods outlined in the Rails i18n guide. You'll have to make that before_filter a bit cleverer. Perhaps something like:

```
if self.kind_of? RailsAdmin::ApplicationController
  I18n.locale = :en
else
  # Your current code
end
```

Comment: did similar: I18n.locale = :en if is_a?(RailsAdmin::ApplicationController) just thought there's a better solution. thank you.

Comment: Maybe the rails_admin people will take a patch to allow you to set this in their config? I agree checking the class is icky! :)

Comment: the question is, how to bring back the old locale after going back to the main app